# Ejabberd number of packets sent and received limited to 61 per second

Tags: ejabberd

I am using latest Ejabberd and grapherl for monitoring. All metrics appear to be fine except Packets sent and received. Here is the graph for packet sent. This is same for received:
[user_send_packet (X-axis : datetime Y-axis : number)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p3vP.png)

The graph maximum value goes till 62.
Is there any configuration in ejabberd.yml for increasing this number ?

Answer (score 1):

You should increase the value of [shaper](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#shapers) in ejabberd.yml to increase the limit of connection traffic.

Example:

```
shaper:
  normal: 3000
  fast: 100000
```

Comment: Hi, I changed the settings to above and still the graph indicates 61 packets per second. Any other suggestions ?